# How to encode a DateTime in a QueryString and read it in the asp:QueryStringParameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How to encode a `DateTime` in a `QueryString` and read it in the `asp:QueryStringParameter`?

out: 
(it's a `asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl`)

```
String.Format("~/Reports/Logs/Option_History.aspx?OptionID={0}&time={1}", _
              id, _
              time)
```

in:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="time" 
                          QueryStringField="Time" 
                          Type="DateTime" 
                          ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you tried so far?

Comment: The date does not pass the query string. It does not like the "/"...
I know i could use httputility.htmlencode(time) and then read it as a string in the QueryStringParameter. Then I could use  httputility.htmldecode and cast it as datetime within the function called by the data source, but i wonder if I could format it some way so it's read directly as a datetime by the QueryStringParameter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've answered it yourself, except you're looking for `UrlEncode`. You also need to confirm what format `asp:QueryStringParameter Type="DateTime"` accepts, e.g. it may require `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` irrespective of the region settings of the web server, or it could be that it *is* dependent upon the region settings of the web server, in which case you need an invariant date format like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

**Update**
Here's a working example:

```
String.Format("~/Reports/Logs/Option_History.aspx?OptionID={0}&time={1}", _
              id, _
              HttpUtility.UrlEncode(time.ToString("o")))
```

`ToString("o")` converts it using The [Round-trip ("O", "o") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip)